# Proving the identity $\tan (A)-\sin^2(A)\tan(A) = \cos(A)\sin(A)$

Tags: trigonometry

I came across an interesting question while studying for AS Levels.

> Prove the following identity:
>   $$\tan (A)-\sin^2(A)\tan(A) = \cos(A)\sin(A)$$

Hints and suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: You know that $1-\sin^2A=\cos^2 A$, don't you?

Comment: @OjasSethi Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\tan A-\sin^2 A\tan A=\tan A(1-\sin^2 A)=\tan A\cos^2 A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}\cos^2 A=\sin A\cos A$$